# Passing a value from a User Control to code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm trying to pass a value from a User Control to a code behind without luck. I can write the correct value (IDuser_uc) on the aspx page but I can't pass it to the code behind. Any tips?

User Control

```
protected void FormView_IDuser_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Label IDuserText = FormView_IDuser.FindControl("IDuserLabel") as Label;
            IDuser_uc = Convert.ToString(IDuserText.Text);

    }
```

ASPX page

```
<uc4:IDuser id="IDuser" runat="server" />
<% Response.Write(IDuser.IDuser_uc); // Here correct value %>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     SqlDataSource_userConnections.SelectParameters["IDuser_par"].DefaultValue = IDuser.IDuser_uc ; // Here NO value
     Response.Write("Connections :" + IDuser.IDuser_uc); // Here NO value

    }
```

UPDATE

The problem was due to the fact that the User Control is run after the PageLoad which explains why I got an empty string. To solve the problem I used Page_PreRender instead of Page_Load on the code behind page.

Comment: IDuser_uc.Text [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text(v=vs.110).aspx) hope this helps

Comment: IDuser_uc.Text is not recognized on the code behind page...

Comment: sorry that was crap. what type is `IDuser.IDuser_uc` in last code block? thought it was a label.

Comment: IDuser is the User Control ID and IDuser_uc is a public string declared on the User Control. As explained above I can send the string to the aspx page but not to the code behind

Comment: Still can't find how to fix this problem. I think I'm going crazy in circles.... Any tips?????

Answer (score 0):

Create a public method in your user control. When you post back the page have the Parent.aspx page call the user control method. Example....

1. In your User Control:

   Public string GetUserControlValue()
   {
       return  Label IDuserText;

   }
2. In your Parent ASPX Pgae

   var UserControlString = IDuser_uc.GetUserControlValue();

Comment: Still no value passed. GetUserControlValue() is sending an empty string to the code behind page....